# Web development on PowerPC

Tags: macos, powerpc, php, web-app, g5

I'm interested in LAMP stack and Nodejs stack for **PowerPC** (iMac g5). Do they exist for Mac OS X 10.5.6 PPC?

Comment: [Homebrew supports 10.5](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) so what happens when you install homebrew and [then try to install node](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) from source? My guess is someone adept at fixing minor build issues could patch things together and recompile the entire toolchain for PPC, but you might have an easier time at 10.6 which does imply getting on Intel. LAMP and javascript surely run on PPC, but might be quite outdated for node to be happy or even functional.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to install some Linux on my G5 and try web development from there? Would that work?

Comment: The skills and knowledge you'd gain trying to get homebrew working will serve you if you need to try Linux later. There are some people here that can help with specific homebrew errors, so if you try that we can help. You could try either I suppose. I'd say start work and adjust when you run into a roadblock.

Comment: Just wondering, would it be a bad idea (efficiency-wise) for OP to run everything inside a headless Linux VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still use Mac OS X 10.5.8 for web development. It has a built-in Apache server with PHP, but I easily installed MAMP.

As for node.js, the V8 engine under the hood requires Intel CPU, but RingoJS and Rhino work fine. There is Rhinode for node.js-like API on top of Rhino, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there's a port of V8 for ppc! https://github.com/andrewlow/v8ppc